# Retrofit:2.0.0-beta2 http call and response handling

Tags: retrofit

My backend returns this json object to signal a succesful new user registration
{
  "error": false,
  "message": "You have been successfully registered"
}

and this to signal the account already exists
{
  "error": true,
  "message": "Sorry, this email already exists"
}

and this on other registration failure
{
  "error": true,
  "message": "An error occurred!! Please try again"
}

I want to use retrofit:2.0.0-beta2 to make an asynchronous http call and handle the response to take the use to the home page or redirect to the login page accordingly.

Here's my POJO:
public class User {

```
public final String email, firstname, lastname, city, birthday, gender, password;

public User(final String email, final String firstname, final String lastname,
            final String city, final String birthday, final String gender, final String password) {
    this.email = email;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.city = city;
    this.birthday = birthday;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.password = password;
}
```

}
Here's my service:
public interface APIService {

```
@POST("/api/user")
Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a extra class to handled response.

```
public class ResponseApi{
    public String error;
    public String message;
}
```

You're inferface

```
@POST("/api/user")
Call<ResponseApi> createUser(@Body User user);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `onResponse` listener and handle the redirects or any other action inside it.

For example:

```java
  protected void loginAttempt(final View v) {
    authUser = new HashMap<>();
    authUser.put("email", email.getText().toString());
    authUser.put("password", password.getText().toString());

    Call call = SubApplication.api.authUser(authUser);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
            try {
                JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                Log.d("LoginActivity", "onResponse: " + responseObject.toString());

                if (responseObject.getBoolean("success") == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), getString(R.string.error_login_success), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), getString(R.string.error_login_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("LoginActivity", "Exception: " + e);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), getString(R.string.error_login_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("LoginActivity", "onFailure: " + t);
        }
    });
```